# Need to create a SSIS package which inserts data in destination column

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, plsql, ssis

I need to transform one single column values(columnA) from TABLE A in one database to another column B in TABLE B in some other database.

When i transfer columnA for example has (Employee names) but in the destination TABLE B it should be the (Employee ID). I have a lookup table which has the employeeID for the matching employee name.

Conditions:
I need only one single column gets updated in the destination TABLE B. without affecting any other columns.(Is it possible to insert in that way ? i know insertion involves all the columns to be involved)

I know this can be done in SSIS and i have created 
* source oledb
*Lookup Transform
*Destination OLEDB

But the problem is at the destination output TABLE B the lookup transform is inserting NULL values to the unmatched column.

Can someone please guide me which is the best way to do this ?
Similarly  i need to include various flows for the destination table from various databases.

Comment: Can you post an image of the data flow? It sounds like you need an "OLE DB Command" transformation after the Lookup to update table B.

Comment: I dont find any uplod image tab here. Is there any way I to share the package flow here ?

Comment: I tried for uploading the image.but it says i need atleast 10 points to upload the image. The flow is like  *SourceOLEDB *Conditional Split * LookUP transform * Destination OLEDB......

Comment: Will the Lookup always find a record? If so then you will need the "OLE DB Command" transformation and an update SQL statement to change the record. If the Lookup is likely to fail then you will need a "Destination OLE DB" attached to the Lookup failure

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a SQL Command as your destination, and have it do an UPDATE command to update your destination table to update the value of the EmployeeID column with the ID from the lookup table.   If they are both on the same database, you can do a join in the command, otherwise you should use a Lookup transformation to get the ID based on the name.